# Printer Module: Show link base on Content Type

Tags: nodes

Let say I have content type A, B, C and D. How can I show the [Printer](https://www.drupal.org/project/print) Module's Link on B and D only? The one with PDF version, and ePub Version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit the content type and go to **Printer, email and PDF version** and choose to display or not.

[image]